# Defaults in http routes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I created two routes

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "1", "int/{controller}/{Id}",
            new { action = "GetById" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "The rest", "int/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" });
```

thinking that I can then create a controller with

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Text(string text = null)
    {
    }
```

and call it with `/int/sandpit2/text?text=xxx`, but I'm getting 404 with "No action was found on the controller 'Sandpit2' that matches the name 'GetById'."

Can I somehow have the 1st rule to call `GetById`, but if there is no `GetById` method have other routes try to match instead of getting `404s`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the routing happens in 3 separate phases:

- Finding a matching route
- Finding a matching controller based on the route
- Finding the matching action within the matched controller

So in your case, first route qualifies for the URL and comes to your controller. Then it cannot find a matching parameter for `Id` so then says cannot find a matching action. If you change it to this should work:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Text(string id = null)
{
   ...
}
```